# Python pandas: How to group by and count unique values based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

I have datafarme df:

```
id name number
1 sam   76
2 sam    8
2 peter  8 
4 jack   2
```

I would like to group by on 'id' column and count the number of unique values based on the pair of (name,number)?

```
id count(name-number)
1    1
2    2
4    1
```

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
df.groupby('id')[('number','name')].nunique().reset_index()
```

Comment: /@User  your table does not make sense there 1 with count 1, it should be 2,  There  are 2 number 2's, two "sam, and 2 '8's. please give a clear example data and output.

Answer (score 9):

You can just combine two `groupby`s to get the desired result.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 2, 4], "name": ["sam", "sam", "peter", "jack"], "number": [8, 8, 8, 2]})
group = df.groupby(['id','name','number']).size().groupby(level=0).size()
```

The first `groupby` will count the complete set of original combinations (and thereby make the columns you want to count unique). The second `groupby` will count the unique occurences per the column you want (and you can use the fact that the first `groupby` put that column in the index).

The result will be a Series. If you want to have DataFrame with the right column name (as you showed in your desired result) you can use the `aggregate` function:

```
group = df.groupby(['id','name','number']).size().groupby(level=0).agg({'count(name-number':'size'})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3, 4], "name": ["sam", "sam", "peter", "jack"], "number": [8, 8, 8, 2]})
g = df.groupby(["name", "number"])
print g.groups
```

which gives:

```
{('jack', 2): [3], ('peter', 8): [2], ('sam', 8): [0, 1]}
```

to get number of unique entries per pair you can do:

```
for p in g.groups: 
    print p, " has ", len(g.groups[p]), " entries"
```

which gives:

```
('peter', 8)  has  1  entries
('jack', 2)  has  1  entries
('sam', 8)  has  2  entries
```

**update:**

the OP asked for result in dataframe. One way to get this is to use `aggregate` with the length function, which will return a dataframe with the number of unique entries per pair:

```
d = g.aggregate(len)
print d.reset_index().rename(columns={"id": "num_entries"})
```

gives:

```
    name  number  num_entries
0   jack       2           1
1  peter       8           1
2    sam       8           2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was more hoping that I would be able to fo it with a python pandas trick with a dataframe, Do you know how to do it that way?

Comment: do you know how can I get the unique groups? because currently the scrips give also duplicates pairs

Comment: I actually just realized your answer does not answer what I have asked. Because I would like to know the number of unique (name, number) pairs per id. and what you have coded give the number of entries per (name,number) pair

Comment: Thanks for great answer for grouping and counting in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of unique values for column combinations:

```
grouped= df.groupby('name').number.unique()
for k,v in grouped.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

output:

```
jack
[2]
peter
[8]
sam
[76  8]
```

To get number of values of one column based on another:

```
df.groupby('name').number.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

output:

```
number  2   8   76
name            
jack    1.0 0.0 0.0
peter   0.0 1.0 0.0
sam     0.0 1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.drop('id', 
  axis=1).drop_duplicates().shape[0]).reset_index()
```